# reading MVC Label Value from View with in same View (.cshtml)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a label in my MVC4's .cshtml file:

```
Name : @Html.Label("A Developer", new {id="lblName"})<br />
```

i want to use this label value in this same view here:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Dev Details", "GetDevDetailsByName", "Dev", new { devName = lblName})
```

the above action link is obviously incorrect.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    window.location = "@Html.ActionLink("Get Dev Details", "GetDevDetailsByName", "Dev", new { devName = "----"})".replace("----", $('#lblName').val());
});
```